# Flex Advance datagrid date column sorting problem

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to sort `ArrayCollection` with following dates, and getting unexpected results.

```
14-Apr-1980
01-Feb-1975
30-Dec-1977
27-Oct-1968
```

I'm using following code to sort,

```
private function sortDate(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int
{
    var d1:Number = (new Date(Date.parse(obj1.date))).getTime();
    var d2:Number = (new Date(Date.parse(obj2.date))).getTime();
    if(d1 < d2) 
    {
        return -1;
    } 
    else if(d1 == d2) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And it's called like ,

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="dob"
headerText="Date of birth:"
sortCompareFunction="sortDate"
dataTipFunction="dateFormat" />
</mx:columns>
```

Results are coming like ,

```
27-Oct-1968
01-Feb-1975
14-Apr-1980
30-Dec-1977
```

What am I missing ?

(Note : my date format in `AdvancedDataGrid` is `DD-MMM-YYYY` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the date separator from hyphen (`-`) to a slash (`/`) or a `space`. And make sure that the `sortableColumns` property of `AdvancedDataGrid` is `true`

From the livedocs page for [`Date.parse()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html#parse()) method.

> The year month and day terms can be separated by a forward slash (`/`) or by spaces, but never by a dash (`-`).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work as well . For ref here is some chunk ,

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{arrColl}" width="564"  height="388" sortableColumns="true">


<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="dob" headerText="Date of birth:" sortCompareFunction="sortDate" dataTipFunction="formatDate"  />

Format function,

private function formatDate(item:Object):String {
return dateFormatter.format(item.dob);
}

Sort function code is still same as I've mentioned in my last post.

Comment: post the data provider - did you change the hyphens to slashes?